# Why are metaballs created with twice the input radius?

Tags: objects, meta-objects

I am relatively new to working with Metaballs and am confused by something quite basic.

In Blender 2.82 (latest release), when I add a new Metaball and specify a radius, the radius that is actually applied to the Metaball and is listed in the properties panel is exactly twice the specified radius.

What is going on here? Is there something I don't understand about Metaballs, or possibly a bug?

[image]

Edit: note the actual diameter of the metaball is 4m:

[image]

Comment: Hello :). No woriess, this is correct. The 1m is *Radius*. Those 2 meters are *Diameter*.

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't think that's correct -- see edit in the OP, the measured diameter of the metaball is actually 4m.

Comment: Ouch, my bad, sorry :). You're right, it seems the original *Radius value* is multiplied by 2. That's definitely weird.

Comment: I'd call it a bug (even though a small one). Nothing suggests this is intended behavior. Are you going to report it or should I? :).

Comment: Thanks I will report it